# Changing 2 Function into one function

Tags: c#, linq

I have two functions that are similar. The only differences is that their using two different models.Is there a way to dynamically initialize the class that is going to be use.

```
 ITagRepository tagRepo = new TagRepository();
 ICategoryRepository catRepo = new CategoryRepository();

public void AddTagsDontExist(string tags)
    {
        var allTags = tagRepo.GetAllQueryAble();
        string[] tag = tags.Split(',');

        foreach (var item in tag)
        {
            if (allTags.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(item)).Count() == 0)
            {
                tagRepo.Add(new Tag
                 {
                     Name = item.ToString(),
                     DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
                     LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
                     IsDeleted = false
                 });
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddCategoriesDontExist(string Categories)
    {
        var allCategory = catRepo.GetAllQueryAble();
        string[] Category = Categories.Split(',');

        foreach (var item in Category)
        {
            if (allCategory.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(item)).ToArray().Count() == 0)
            {
                catRepo.Add(new Category
                {
                    Name = item.ToString(),
                    DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
                    LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    IsDeleted = false
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can pass an extra parameter to method ? Also I don't know why you have to separate classes since they both have same fields. Why don't use one class with extra field i.e `type` or something

Comment: Are you allowed to change the interfaces so that you can make both of them implement another, new, interface which specifies an `Add()` and a `GetAllQueryAble()` method?

Comment: Yes i can pass an extra parameter and i can change the interface.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty they are representing two different tables in the database category and Tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would introduce a new interface which contains the methods you need to call, and make the other interfaces implement it. (Note that I've had to guess at the IQueryable stuff.)

```
interface IQueryable // My best guess at this. Substitute with the correct definition!
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

interface IRepository
{
    IEnumerable<IQueryable> GetAllQueryAble();
    void Add(string name, DateTime dateAdded, DateTime lastModifiedDate, bool isDeleted);
}

interface ITagRepository: IRepository
{
    // ...
}

interface ICategoryRepository: IRepository
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you can implement the method as follows (I've cleaned it up a bit):

```
public void AddItems(string items, IRepository repository)
{
    var allTags = repository.GetAllQueryAble();
    string[] tag = items.Split(',');

    foreach (var item in tag)
    {
        if (!allTags.Any(e => e.Name.Contains(item)))
        {
            repository.Add
            (
                item,
                DateTime.Now,
                DateTime.Now,
                false
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you can call that from the other methods like this:

```
public void AddTagsDontExist(string tags)
{
    AddItems(tags, tagRepo);
}

public void AddCategoriesDontExist(string categories)
{
    AddItems(categories, catRepo);
}
```

The implementation of the `Add()` methods would look like this (example shown only for ITagRepository implementation):

```
public sealed class TagRepository : IRepository
{
    public string GetAllQueryAble()
    {
        return ""; // Replace with real implementation.
    }

    public void Add(string name, DateTime dateAdded, DateTime lastModifiedDate, bool isDeleted)
    {
        this.Add(new Tag(name, dateAdded, lastModifiedDate, isDeleted));
    }
}
```

[EDIT]

Thinking about it, you may also need to add an interface for the items in the repository so that you can get at the `.Name` fields, but that would be a similar refactoring that uses the same approach as the other interfaces, so you should be able to extrapolate from that.

Here's an example, where I've invented a new `IRepositoryItem` interface. Note how the `Tag` class implements it:

```
interface IRepositoryItem
{
    string Name { get; }
}

interface IRepository
{
    IEnumerable<IRepositoryItem> GetAllQueryAble();
    void Add(string name, DateTime dateAdded, DateTime lastModifiedDate, bool isDeleted);
}

interface ITagRepository: IRepository
{
    // ...
}

interface ICategoryRepository: IRepository
{
    // ...
}

public sealed class Tag: IRepositoryItem
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "TODO: Implementation";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the clear answer. The answer pointed me in the right direction. I had to do some modification to my repository but its working now with less code.

Answer (score 0):

There might be such a possibility, you could use generic method that would accept type that has overlapping properties.

Here's example how it could look like

```
public interface ICategoryOrTag
{
  string Name  {get; set;}
  DateTime DateAdded  {get; set;}
  DateTime LastModifiedDate  {get; set;}
  bool  IsDeleted  {get; set;}
}

public class Category : ICategoryOrTag
{
  //Category specific 
}

public class Tag : ICategoryOrTag
{
  //Tag specific 
}

public void AddEntityDontExist<T>(string entities) where T : ICategoryOrTag, new()
    {
        var allEntities = entityRepo<T>.GetAllQueryAble();
        string[] entity = entities.Split(',');

        foreach (var item in entity)
        {
            if (allEntities.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(item)).ToArray().Count() == 0)
            {
                entityRepo.Add(new T
                {
                    Name = item.ToString(),
                    DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
                    LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    IsDeleted = false
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you realize his repositories are not directly compatible with whatever object you are specifying in your example as repositories? I mean, whatever `entityRepo` is, it cannot be ported to the question's solution directly

Comment: +1, but you'll need to have `where T : ICategoryOrTag, new()`.

Comment: @Leo it's a possibility, if he is willing to spend the effort. Same thing would apply for repositories, they would have to be generic. I don't think there is other solution is there?

Comment: @LIUFA of course it is a possibility...but I'm just surprised that you don't even mention it...he'll need to re-write his repositories and there's always a chance that he can't afford to